# How to take backup of repositories in Plastic SCM?

Tags: version-control, backup, restore, plasticscm

How to take backup of repositories in Plastic SCM ?
is taking a manual backup of database is enough ?
will I be able to restore and start using the repositories in future if system server crashes ?
Or is there any other method or interface to do this job ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be covered by the chapter "[Backup and restore](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#Chapter9:Backupandrestore)" of the Plastic SCM (4.xw) Administration guide:

> The backup and restore procedures are closely related to the database backend used in Plastic SCM

so yes, backing up the database seems enough.